# Como compilar códigos .cpp que possuem interfaces e implementações separadas no g++?

Tags: c++, interface, gcc

Estou estudando C++ pelo livro da ***Deitel***, e estou tentando compilar um programa onde temos um arquivo `gradebook.h` que é a interface, `gradebook.cpp` que é a implementação e `test_gradebook_header_file.cpp` que é o código que contém a função `main` e a instância da classe `GradeBook`.

Está dando um erro:

> undefined reference to GradeBook::GradeBook

e isso é o mesmo pro restante das funções membros, fiz tudo como ensina, já verifiquei se há algum erro na digitação, mas está tudo certo. Suponho que o problema esteja relacionado a linkagem. Quero utilizar o `g++` para fazer isso mas não sei os passos corretos a seguir.

Aqui está a interface:

```
#include <string>

using namespace std;

// interface da classe GradeBook
class GradeBook
{
public:
    GradeBook(string name_course_param);
    void setCourseName(string name_course_param);
    string getCourseName();
    void displayMessage();
private:
    string courseName;
};
```

Aqui está a implementação:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "gradebook.h"

using namespace std;

GradeBook::GradeBook(string name_course_param)
{
    setCourseName(name_course_param);
}

void GradeBook::setCourseName(string name_course_param)
{
    courseName = name_course_param;
}

string GradeBook::getCourseName()
{
    return courseName;
}

void GradeBook::displayMessage()
{
    cout << "Welcome to the grade book for\n" << getCourseName()
      << "!" << endl;
}
```

Aqui está o programa para teste:

```
// Utilizando a classe GradeBook incluindo o header file gradebook.h
#include <iostream>
#include "gradebook.h" // incluindo interface da classe

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    // criando duas instâncias da classe GradeBook
    GradeBook gradebook1("CS101 Introduction to C++ Programming");
    GradeBook gradebook2("CS102 Data Structures in C++");

    cout << "gradebook1 created for course: " << gradebook1.getCourseName()
      << "\ngradebook2 created for course: " << gradebook2.getCourseName()
      << endl;
}
```

Comment: Favor incluir os códigos-fonte dos arquivos. O erro diz que não está encontrando a classe GradeBook. Cuidado com o case-sensitive do C/C++!

Comment: Coloque também a linha de comando que está usando pra compilar e ligar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você não está compilando a implementação da classe...

```
g++ -o gradebook gradebook.cpp main.cpp
```

Comment: Muito obrigado @José X., me ajudou muito. Agora vou continuar aprendendo mais. Pensei que teria que recorrer a IDEs para fazer esse trabalho. Valeu!